# Cannot complete resetting MacBook with Sierra - HD locked. How can I unlock it?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

MacBook with Sierra -
Disk utility erase completed OK - 
Reinstall Sierra not possible HD is locked. 
How can I unlock it?

Answer (score 1):

Hold down Command, Option and R when startup chime sounds, choose Mac HDD then Reinstall OSX.